# Taking result from SQL/T-SQL Subselect into the parent select statement

Tags: t-sql

I want to extend `ListA` with `Company` coming from `@MyList.CompanyNo`, plese refer to the code listing

Data&Init:

```
begin /*Just the init data*/
DECLARE @MyList TABLE (Mail nvarchar(max), CompanyNo int)
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('...com',20)
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('...com',230)
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('...com',120)
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('...com',223)
end 

--DECLARE
DECLARE @ListA TABLE (Id nvarchar(max), Mail nvarchar(max))
DECLARE @ListB TABLE (Id nvarchar(max), Mail nvarchar(max),Company int)
```

Starting point(this works):

```
INSERT INTO @ListA(Id,Mail) select someId,name from [somedb].[dbo].aers where name IN (SELECT Mail FROM @MyList)
```

I was trying to do it the following way:

```
INSERT INTO @ListB(Id,Mail,Company) select someId,name,@MyList.CompanyNo from [somedb].[dbo].aers where name IN (SELECT Mail FROM @MyList)
```

So actually I want to extend `ListB` with the corrosponding `@MyList.CompanyNo`.

Thanks, what can I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `JOIN` based on condition from `WHERE`:

```
INSERT INTO @ListB(Id,Mail,Company) 
select a.someId,a.name,m.CompanyNo  
from [somedb].[dbo].aers a
join @MyList m
  ON a.name = m.Mail;
```